# unable to store an image in an NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, uiimage, nsmutablearray, xcode4.3

I am trying to save an image in an NSMutable array and it is not working

here is what I am doing

```
[imagesList addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"]];
```

after executing this line I noticed that the number of objects remains 0 
any reason ?

Thanks

I repeate this code in several areas :

Globally I declare :

```
NSMutableArray *imagesList;
NSUserDefaults *imagesHistory;
```

in my viewdidload method I write:

```
imagesHistory=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  //imagesHistory is created globallt as NSUserDefault imagesHistory
[imagesHistory setObject:imagesList forKey:@"images history"];

UIImage *image;
image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];

[imagesList addObject:image];
imagesHistory=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[imagesHistory setObject:imagesList forKey:@"images history"];
```

and in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions I write : (even though I don t need to do it when I am adding strings ...)

```
 imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Have you tried making the image on a separate line, and seeing if it is `nil` or not?  Are you sure `imagesList` has been allocated and initialized properly?

Comment: Either the image can't be loaded (there is no b.png) or imagesList isn't actually mutable.

Comment: @DanF : I made it on two lines ( I creaded a UIImage variable assigned the image to it and I can see that the memory was allocated to this variable) and then I added it to the NSMUtablearray and still the object wasn t added . imagesList is a global variable and from experience I do t need to init and alloc it , or am I missing something?

Comment: @DrummerB: the image exists and imagesList is Mutable

Comment: Of course you need to alloc and init it. That's your problem then.

Comment: @DrummerB : look at my comments below

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of whether it is a global variable or not, you still need to call `alloc` and `init` SOMEWHERE for the object.  If you intend to use it throughout your app, then `appDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` is a decent place to add this call:

```
imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Do you have some more lines of code to show, around where you're adding the object for us to see how you're determining the number of objects in the array?  Also, the declaration of your `imagesList` is helpful information

Comment: What exactly are you doing to determine that there are 0 objects in the imagesList?

Answer (score 1):

Is your empty array being retained? If you're not using Automatic Reference Counting, there's a good chance you're initializing the array with the following

```
imagesList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

but it's not being retained. You'll want to retain the empty array so it gets appended to further on in your code.

```
imagesList = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];
```

Just don't forget to release the array when you're all done with it, in `viewDidUnload` or wherever is appropriate.

Comment: I am using ARC so no need to retain ( I tried to add "retain" and it did not allow me) ...

Answer (score 0):

You're allocating/initing `imagesList` AFTER you try to add an object.  You need to alloc/init `imageList` before you add anything to it.

To make sure it's there, try something like this:

`if (!imagelist) imageList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];`

If it exists, and you're still having this problem, it's possible that you're allocating/initing a new NSMutableArray and assigning it to `imageList` after you've added the object.  This means the old array would be discarded and you'd be left with a new array with zero items.

Comment: I followed your advice and tried adding this line in the app delegate and also just before adding the object and still encountering the same issue ...

Comment: Is it possible you're allocating/initing too many time?  See my updated answer.

Comment: I checked and it I only allocat the variable one .
I also made a small test and found out that if I change the image in the addobject to a string , it works perfectly fine ...

Comment: It sounds like there's a problem in the image itself then.  Maybe it's not actually a png or perhaps it didn't loaded correctly into Xcode.  I'd remove it from Xcode, try to load it back in.  Also, make sure the file name matches perfectly, including caps.  A stray capital letter will prevent it from loading on devices (though I think the simulator will still load it).  If none of that works, maybe recreate the image?  I don't know how difficult that would be but that's the last thing I can think of.

Comment: I tried to add another image that I am actually using .. still the same problem

Comment: In all honesty, I'm not sure.  UIImage should return `nil` if it can't find the image.  You'll get an error if you try to add `nil` to a NSMutableArray.  The only thing I can think of is there is another part of your code removing the image or replacing the array with a new one.

Answer (score 0):

try `UIImageView *image;
image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"b.png"];`

also, in `@property(nonatomic,retain)` use 'strong' instead of 'retain'